# Sqlalchemy mixins / and event listener

Tags: python, events, model, sqlalchemy

I am attempting 2 new things at once, so assistance in both simplifying and clarifying is appreciated.

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declared_attr
from sqlalchemy import Column, Float, event

class TimeStampMixin(object):

    @declared_attr
    def __tablename__(cls):
        return cls.__name__.lower()

    created = Column(Float)
    modified = Column(Float)
    def __init__(self, created = None,
                       modified = None):
        self.created = created
        self.modified = modified

def create_time(mapper, connection, target):
    target.created = time()

#def modified_time(mapper, connection, target):
#    target.modified = time()

event.listen(TimeStampMixin, 'before_insert', create_time)
#event.listen(TimeStampMixin, 'before_update', modified_time)
```

So I want to create a mixin I can apply in any class:

```
class MyClass(TimeStampMixin, Base):
    etc, etc, etc
```

This class inherits functionality that creates a timestamp on creation and creates/modifies a timestamp on update.

on import I get this error:

```
raise exc.UnmappedClassError(class_)
sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedClassError: Class 'db.database.TimeStampMixin' is not mapped
```

aaaand I'm stumped at this point.

Comment: can you post the *actual* traceback?  Also, what are you trying to accomplish with this line: `event.listen(TimeStampMixin, 'before_insert', create_time)`?  There's no way that could work, because `TimeStampMixin` is *not* an SQLAlchemy class (it's descended from object), so SQLAlchemy has no way of knowing what table it should map to.

Comment: That error is the bottom of the actual traceback. What I'm trying to accomplish is what I was trying to accomplish, but now that both I've come back to it and you've pointed it out I see that sqlalchemy won't recognize it....but like I said trying to do two newish things at once, so much I will miss.

Comment: well the key thing to remember is that nothing is really magic in SQLAlchemy, so that's why you just need to be specific with it :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's what I'd do to listen on `before_insert` events: add a `classmethod` to your `TimeStampMixin` that registers the current class and handles setting creation time.

E.g.

```
class TimeStampMixin(object):

    # other class methods

    @staticmethod
    def create_time(mapper, connection, target):
        target.created = time()

    @classmethod
    def register(cls):
        sqlalchemy.event.listen(cls, 'before_insert', cls.create_time)
```

That way, you can:

1. Easily extend and change what you listen for and what you register.
2. Override the create_time method for certain classes
3. Be explicit about which methods need to have their timestamps set.

You can use it simply:

```
class MyMappedClass(TimeStampMixin, Base):
    pass

MyMappedClass.register()
```

Simple, very clear, no magic, but still encapsulates like you want.

Comment: @blueblank, if you are interested, `staticmethod` is just a builtin example of `descriptors` in Python (which is also how methods, classmethods, and properties are handled). You can read more about [the Python data model here](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html) or see the specific [howto guide for descriptors](http://docs.python.org/howto/descriptor.html)

Comment: One possible disadvantage of this is that `create_time` can't be overridden.  Since `register` is a class method, couldn't `create_time` also be a classmethod?

Comment: @mwhite that's not really true. If you define `create_time` on `MyMappedClass`,  `register()` will use that instead. Classmethod wouldn't be any different, it's always going to be bound to a function in `register()` so even monkey-patching the class won't change it.

Comment: Ah, right, thanks.  What about `event.listen(..., lambda: cls.create_time)`?

Anyway, wouldn't `MyMappedClass.create_time()` be able to call super() to call `TimeStampMixin.create_time()`?

Comment: I guess you could. For simplicity I would probably not want to futz around too much with inheritance. But yes that would work.

Answer (score 39):

Attach your listener inside the class method and it will attach the event to the child class.

```
class TimeStampMixin(object):
    @staticmethod
    def create_time(mapper, connection, target):
        target.created = time()

    @classmethod
    def __declare_last__(cls):
        # get called after mappings are completed
        # http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/extensions/declarative.html#declare-last
        event.listen(cls, 'before_insert', cls.create_time)
```

Comment: And what's the difference with the previous answer?

Comment: @SergeBelov The use of `__declare_last__`, I guess

Comment: Madth3 is right, I miss-indented my code sorry about that. I'm using this code and I didn't find any time loss compare to attaching event to each of my child class.

Comment: This is definitely a better answer - I didn't know about `__declare_last__`.

Comment: If there are several mixins using `__declare_last__`, will they be overridden?

Comment: I didn't know about `__declare_last__` and i think also this is the right ANSWER

Comment: Does not work if a single model includes multiple mixins.

Answer (score 5):

The best way in modern SqlAlchemy is to use the `@listens_for` decorator with `propagate=True`.

```
from datetime import datetime
from sqlalchemy import Column, Float
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declared_attr
from sqlalchemy.event import listens_for

class TimestampMixin():
    @declared_attr
    def created(cls):
        return Column(DateTime(timezone=True))

@listens_for(TimeStampMixin, "init", propagate=True)
def timestamp_init(target, args, kwargs):
    kwargs["created"] = datetime.utcnow()
```

Answer (score 3):

you can also do it like this:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm.interfaces import MapperExtension

class BaseExtension(MapperExtension):
    """Base entension class for all entities """

    def before_insert(self, mapper, connection, instance):
        """ set the created_at  """
        instance.created = datetime.datetime.now()

    def before_update(self, mapper, connection, instance):
        """ set the updated_at  """
        instance.modified = datetime.datetime.now()


class TimeStampMixin(object):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    created = Column(DateTime())
    modified = Column(DateTime())

    __table_args__ = {
        'mysql_engine': 'InnoDB',
        'mysql_charset': 'utf8'
    }
    __mapper_args__ = { 'extension': BaseExtension() }
```

and define your classes like:

```
class User(TimeStampMixin, Base):
```

Comment: Note that MapperExtension has been [deprecated](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/deprecated.html) since 0.7.