# SQLAlchemy events after_create for all models

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm working on a project that requires generic customisation to every model that is created. The way I have done most of the work to date is by model inheritance. Here is my code block to give you a better idea:

app.core.dba.mixins:

```
class AuditExtension(MapperExtension):
    """
    AuditExtension enforces the audit column values, and ensures any interaction with
    SQLAlchemy cannot override the values
    """

    def before_insert(self, mapper, connection, instance):
        instance.created_dt = datetime.utcnow()
        instance.created_by = audit_session_user()

        instance.updated_dt = datetime.utcnow()
        instance.updated_by = audit_session_user()

    def before_update(self, mapper, connection, instance):
        # Never update the created columns
        instance.created_dt = instance.created_dt
        instance.created_by = instance.created_by

        instance.updated_dt = datetime.utcnow()
        instance.updated_by = audit_session_user()


class AuditColumns(object):

    """ Generate the column schema for simple table level auditing. """
    created_dt = Column(DateTime,
                        default=datetime.utcnow(),
                        nullable=False)
    created_by = Column(String(64),
                        #ForeignKey('operators.username', ondelete="RESTRICT"),
                        nullable=False)

    updated_dt = Column(DateTime,
                        default=datetime.utcnow(),
                        nullable=False,
                        onupdate=datetime.utcnow())

    updated_by = Column(String(64),
                        #ForeignKey('operators.username', ondelete="RESTRICT"),
                        nullable=False)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'extension': AuditExtension()}
```

My models then inherit AuditColumns:

```
class ObjectTypes(Base, AuditColumns):
    __tablename__ = 'object_types'

    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False, unique=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name
```

My problem is; my solution for forcing the audit data works as long as operation is contained to the flask app and SQLAlchemy - this does not prevent anyone with database access to updating the values.

Therefore, I now need to implement a trigger on each model that inherits the AuditColumns. I found this post [Sqlalchemy mixins / and event listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12753450/sqlalchemy-mixins-and-event-listener) - and it describes a method for before_insert/update (which I've previous had working), but not for "after_create".

Now, I've added this to my mixins file code (straight after my audit code above:

```
trig_ddl = DDL("""
            CREATE TRIGGER tr_audit_columns BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
            ON test_table
            FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE
            ss_test();
        """)

event.listen(AuditColumns, 'after_create', trig_ddl)
```

However, when I run a test case:

```
Base.metadata.drop_all(db.get_engine(app))
Base.metadata.create_all(db.get_engine(app))
```

I get the following error:

```
File "D:\Devel\flask-projects\sc2\app\core\dba\mixins.py", line 59, in <module>
    event.listen(AuditColumns, 'after_create', trig_ddl)
  File "D:\Devel\flask-projects\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\event.py", line 43, in listen
    (identifier, target))
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: No such event 'after_create' for target '<class 'app.core.dba.mixins.AuditColumns'>'
```

I'm guessing this is because it's not a table yet; but how would I globally define an event listener for a table create, that will execute this type of command?

I know I have to make the trig_ddl dynamic (which I don't think will be too hard, but I at least need to figure out the global element of this).

Basically, I don't want people to have to manually write in each model this event when it's clearly tied to these audit columns.

Any push in the right direction would be great.

Comment: would it be completely unfeasible to mandate that all changes has to go via the orm? trying to keep you business logic in both the application _and_ the database seems like a recipe for future headaches. It seems perfectly reasonable to decide to use an orm, keep the logic in the application layer and disallow (or be very careful with) direct db access via process/access controls

Comment: Currently, we use direct DB access a lot for migrations, bulk data fixes etc.. But it's conceivable that all these things could be forced via unittests written in py/sqlalchemy in the future...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well you'd need to piggyback the events here so you can get at that `Table`:

```
@event.listens_for(AuditColumns, "instrument_class", propagate=True)
def instrument_class(mapper, class_):
    if mapper.local_table is not None:
        trigger_for_table(mapper.local_table)

def trigger_for_table(table):
    trig_ddl = DDL("""
                CREATE TRIGGER tr_%s_audit_columns BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
                ON %s
                FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE
                ss_test();
            """ % (table.name, table.name))

    event.listen(table, 'after_create', trig_ddl)
```

any subclass of `AuditColumms` is mapped, `mapper.local_table` will be there already (as will `class.__table__`, same thing), you apply the DDL event at that point.

Comment: OK, I've gone to the docs and from what I can work out this works by first listening for any new model that tries to inherit AuditColumns - it then uses the mapper to figure out the table inheriting the extension, then calls the trigger_for_table function to simply generate the DDL and generate the listener for THAT specific model? It would be really great if you had any further info on instrument_class as the documentation is a little vague (or maybe a little too specific that I don't quite understand it)... By the way - this works; but I really understand WHY it works.

Comment: instrument_class is an event, "do this as soon as a class which subclasses AuditColumns is mapped to a Table".  its not unlike if you created a metaclass that did something on `__init__()`, e.g. when a new class is created.