# sqlalchemy mixin: after_create not firing in child

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, orm

I am working on an ORM style version of the [pq library](https://github.com/malthe/pq) (PostgreSQL powered python queue system) where users can have their own queue model. It also has added features such as bulk insert/get, asynchronous support and more (if all goes well I'll be able to publish it).

I am having difficulties **creating a trigger** (I use a PostgreSQL notification system) **automatically after table creation** (I want to make the usage as simple as possible so that would be much better than adding an additional classmethod for creating the trigger).

This is similar to the answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17583371/10551772) however I cannot use this solution because **I need to pass a connection** (for escaping SQL identifiers by checking the dialect of the connection and for checking if objects exist beforehand).

Here is my attempt at it based on the post I mentionned earlier. I apologize for the long code but I figured I had to include a bit of context.

## Base model

```py
from sqlalchemy import (BIGINT, Column, func, Index, nullslast,
                        nullsfirst, SMALLINT, TIMESTAMP)
from sqlalchemy.orm import declared_attr, declarative_mixin
from sqlalchemy.event import listens_for

# this is the function that returns the base model
def postgres_queue_base(schema:str='public', tz_aware:bool=True, use_trigger:bool=True) -> 'PostgresQueueBase':

    @declarative_mixin  # this is only for MyPy, it does not modify anything
    class PostgresQueueBase:

        __tablename__ = 'queue'

        @declared_attr
        def __table_args__(cls):
            return (Index(nullsfirst(cls.schedule_at), nullslast(cls.dequeued_at), postgresql_where=(cls.dequeued_at == None)),
                    {'schema':schema})

        id = Column('id', BIGINT, primary_key=True)
        internal_mapping = Column('internal_mapping', BIGINT, nullable=False)
        enqueued_at = Column('enqueued_at', TIMESTAMP(timezone=tz_aware), nullable=False, server_default=func.now())
        dequeued_at = Column('dequeued_at', TIMESTAMP(timezone=tz_aware))
        expected_at = Column(TIMESTAMP(timezone=tz_aware))
        schedule_at = Column(TIMESTAMP(timezone=tz_aware))
        status = Column(SMALLINT, index=True)

    @listens_for(PostgresQueueBase, "instrument_class", propagate=True)
    def instrument_class(mapper, class_):
        print('EVENT INSTRUMENT CLASS')
        if use_trigger and mapper.local_table is not None:
            trigger_for_table(table=mapper.local_table)

    def trigger_for_table(table):
        print('Registering after_create event')

        @listens_for(table, "after_create")
        def create_trigger(table, connection):
            print('AFTER CREATE EVENT')
            # code that creates triggers and logs that (here I'll just print something and put pseudo code in a comment)
            # trig = PostgresQueueTrigger(schema=get_schema_from_model(table), table_name=table.name, connection=connection)
            # trig.add_trigger()
            print('Creating notify function public.notify_job')
            # unique trigger name using hash of schema.table_name (avoids problems with long names and special chars)
            print('Creating trigger trigger_job_5d69fc3870b446d0a1f56a793b799ae3')

    return PostgresQueueBase
```

## When I try the base model

```py
from sqlalchemy import Column, create_engine, INTEGER, TEXT
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base

# IMPORTANT: inherit both a declarative base AND the postgres queue base
Base = declarative_base()
PostgresQueueBase = postgres_queue_base(schema='public')


# create custom queue model
class MyQueue(Base, PostgresQueueBase):

    # optional custom table name (by default it is "queue")
    __tablename__ = 'demo_queue'

    # custom columns
    operation = Column(TEXT)
    project_id = Column(INTEGER)


# create table in database
# change connection string accordingly!
engine = create_engine('postgresql://username:password@localhost:5432/postgres')
Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
```

```
EVENT INSTRUMENT CLASS
Registering after_create event
```

I cannot see "AFTER CREATE EVENT" printed out . How do I get the "after_create" event to be fired?

Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I finally figured it out... The table already existed so the events were never firing. Also the code above has some errors in the events (I could not test them since they were not being executed) and the composite index in **table_args** somehow gets the name """ NULLS FIRST"". I used a hash to have a better name and avoid problems with character limitation or escaping.

```py
import hashlib
from sqlalchemy import (BIGINT, Column, func, Index, nullslast,
                        nullsfirst, SMALLINT, TIMESTAMP)
from sqlalchemy.orm import declared_attr, declarative_mixin
from sqlalchemy.event import listens_for


# this is the function that returns the base model
def postgres_queue_base(schema:str='public', tz_aware:bool=True, use_trigger:bool=True) -> 'PostgresQueueBase':

    @declarative_mixin  # this is only for MyPy, it does not modify anything
    class PostgresQueueBase:

        __tablename__ = 'queue'

        @declared_attr
        def __table_args__(cls):
            # to prevent any problems such as escaping, SQL injection or limit of characters I'll just md5 the table name for the index
            md5 = hashlib.md5(cls.__tablename__.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
            return (Index(f'queue_prio_ix_{md5}', nullsfirst(cls.schedule_at), nullslast(cls.dequeued_at),
                          postgresql_where=(cls.dequeued_at == None)),
                    {'schema':schema})

        id = Column('id', BIGINT, primary_key=True)
        internal_mapping = Column('internal_mapping', BIGINT, nullable=False)
        enqueued_at = Column('enqueued_at', TIMESTAMP(timezone=tz_aware), nullable=False, server_default=func.now())
        dequeued_at = Column('dequeued_at', TIMESTAMP(timezone=tz_aware))
        expected_at = Column(TIMESTAMP(timezone=tz_aware))
        schedule_at = Column(TIMESTAMP(timezone=tz_aware))
        status = Column(SMALLINT, index=True)

    if use_trigger:
        @listens_for(PostgresQueueBase, "instrument_class", propagate=True)
        def class_instrument(mapper, class_):
            if mapper.local_table is not None:
                create_trigger_event(table=mapper.local_table)

        def create_trigger_event(table):
            @listens_for(table, "after_create")
            def create_trigger(target, connection, **kw):
                print('Create trigger')

    return PostgresQueueBase
```