# SQLAlchemy nested model creation one-liner

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, nested

I'm looking to create a new object from **q2**, which fails because the Question class is expecting options to be a dictionary of Options, and it's receiving a dict of dicts instead.

So, unpacking obviously fails with a nested model.

What is the best approach to handle this? Is there something that's equivalent to the elegance of the **dict for a nested model?

**main.py**

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

import models.base

from models.question import Question
from models.option import Option


engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')

models.base.Base.metadata.create_all(engine, checkfirst=True)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()


def create_question(q):

    # The following hard coding works:
    # q = Question(text='test text',
    #                     frequency='test frequency',
    #                     options=[Option(text='test option')]
    #                     )

    question = Question(**q)
    session.add(question)
    session.commit()

q1 = {
    'text': 'test text',
    'frequency': 'test frequency'
}

q2 = {
    'text': 'test text',
    'frequency': 'test frequency',
    'options': [
        {'text': 'test option 123'},
    ]
}

create_question(q1)
# create_question(q2) FAILS
```

**base.py**

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()

from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()
```

**question.py**

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from .base import Base


class Question(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'questions'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    text = Column(String(120), nullable=False)
    frequency = Column(String(20), nullable=False)
    active = Column(Boolean(), default=True, nullable=False)

    options = relationship('Option', back_populates='question')

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Question(id={0}, text={1}, frequency={2}, active={3})>".format(self.id, self.text, self.frequency, self.active)
```

**option.py**

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from .base import Base


class Option(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'options'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    question_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('questions.id'))
    text = Column(String(20), nullable=False)

    question = relationship('Question', back_populates='options')

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Option(id={0}, question_id={1}, text={2})>".format(self.id, self.question_id, self.text)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I liked the answer provided by @Abdou, but wanted to see if I couldn't make it a bit more generic.

I ended up coming up with the following, which should handle any nested model.

```
from sqlalchemy import event, inspect


@event.listens_for(Question, 'init')
@event.listens_for(Option, 'init')
def received_init(target, args, kwargs):

    for rel in inspect(target.__class__).relationships:

        rel_cls = rel.mapper.class_

        if rel.key in kwargs:
            kwargs[rel.key] = [rel_cls(**c) for c in kwargs[rel.key]]
```

Listens for the init event of any specified models, checks for relationships that match the kwargs passed in, and then converts those to the matching class of the relationship.

If anyone knows how to set this up so it can work on all models instead of specifying them, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Just a note, `inspect(target).mapper` is another way of writing `inspect(target.__class__)`.

Comment: @IljaEverilä I just tried inspect(target) vs. inspect(target.__class__) and they provide different objects. inspect(target.__class__) sas a relationships property, whereas the other does not.

Comment: That's why you access the [mapper attribute](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/internals.html#sqlalchemy.orm.state.InstanceState.mapper) of the [`InstanceState`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/internals.html#sqlalchemy.orm.state.InstanceState) object. `inspect(target)` is of course different, `inspect(target).mapper` not so.

Comment: Note: this will fail on relationships where uselist=False. You can add handling for this with `if rel.uselist: kwargs[rel.key] = [rel_cls(**c) for c in kwargs[rel.key]] else: kwargs[rel.key] = rel_cls(**kwargs[rel.key])`

Answer (score 1):

Given that you need to create an `Option` object every time there is an `options` key in the dictionary passed to the `create_question` function, you should use dictionary comprehension to create your options before passing the result to the `Question` instantiator. I would rewrite the function as follows:

```
def create_question(q):

    # The following hard coding works:
    # q = Question(text='test text',
    #                     frequency='test frequency',
    #                     options=[Option(text='test option')]
    #                     )
    q = dict((k, [Option(**x) for x in v]) if k == 'options' else (k,v) for k,v in q.items())
    print(q)
    question = Question(**q)
    session.add(question)
    session.commit()
```

The dictionary comprehension part basically checks if there is an `options` key in the given dictionary; and if there is one, then it creates `Option` objects with the values. Otherwise, it carries on as normal.

The above function generated the following:

```
# {'text': 'test text', 'frequency': 'test frequency'}
# {'text': 'test text', 'frequency': 'test frequency', 'options': [<Option(id=None, question_id=None, text=test option 123)>]}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Building on @Searle's answer, this avoids needing to directly list all models in the decorators, and also provides handling for when `uselist=False` (e.g. 1:1, many:1 relationships):

```py
from sqlalchemy import event
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapper

@event.listens_for(Mapper, 'init')
def received_init(target, args, kwargs):
    """Allow initializing nested relationships with dict only"""
    for rel in db.inspect(target).mapper.relationships:
        if rel.key in kwargs:
            if rel.uselist:
                kwargs[rel.key] = [rel.mapper.class_(**c) for c in kwargs[rel.key]]
            else:
                kwargs[rel.key] = rel.mapper.class_(**kwargs[rel.key])
```

Possible further improvements:

- add handling for if `kwargs[rel.key]` is a model instance (right now this fails if you pass a model instance for relationships instead of a dict)
- allow relationships to be specified as None (right now requires empty lists or dicts)

source: [SQLAlchemy "event.listen" for all models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8907963/sqlalchemy-event-listen-for-all-models)

Answer (score -1):

For SQLAlchemy objects you can simply use `Model.__dict__`